# Is every real sequence of finite length bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, self-learning

My course notes (Mathematics BSc, second year module in real analysis, unpublished) have,

> **Theorem 2.1.8** *If a sequence* $(a_n)$ *is convergent, then it is bounded.*

The proof includes,

> [...] now suppose that $n \leq N$. We then have $$|a_n|\leq\text{max}\{|a_1|,|a_2|,\dots,|a_N|\}.$$

But doesn't assuming the existence of a maximum assume boundedness, the thing to be proved? I'm guessing there's a tacit assumption that "infinities" can only exist at the "end" of a sequence of infinite length, not as singularities within a sequence of finite length. Am I right?

Comment: No, for that part you're just using the fact that any sequence of finitely many elements is bounded.  The other part of the proof will show that the infinitely many elements of the sequence with index greater than $N$ also is bounded.

Comment: If $N$ is taken to be a finite integer, then that maximum exists just fine; a finite sequence of reals is bounded since infinity is not a real number! And intuitively, if the sequence approached infinity, it wouldn’t really be converging

Comment: @FShrike I think "infinity is not a real number" is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @RobertShore "the fact that any sequence of finitely many elements is bounded" is the tacit assumption I was guessing at, so I think your overall answer to my question is "Yes".

Comment: For a finite sequence, it is obvious that the maximum exists. But for the sequence this argument is not yet sufficient, but if you consider that , if the limit is $L$, then there are only finite many entries outside, lets say , the interval $[L-1,L+1]$ , it becomes clear that it also must be bounded.

Comment: @Peter The point of my question was that it wasn't obvious to me that a maximum exists for a finite sequence. I think the missing piece I was looking for was the one given by FShrike, that "infinity is not a real number".